# How to use a Dockerized service in a HTML file [Docker Compose]

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose with this 3 services:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

maptiles_server:
 image: maptiler/tileserver-gl:v4.1.2
 container_name: maptiles_server
 ports:
   - 3065:80
 volumes:
   - .\\app\\static\\assets\\maptiles:/data
 command: --mbtiles 2017-07-03_italy_milan.mbtiles

app:
 build: .
 ports:
  - 8000:2323
 container_name: flask_app
 links: 
   - maptiles_server

nginx:
 container_name: nginx
 build: .\ngnix
 # Bind the port 80 of container to machine port 80
 ports:
   - 90:80
 # Make app as nginx dependency service
 depends_on:
   - app
   - maptiles_server
```

The `app` expose a route to show a HTML map with some coordinates and use `maptiles_server` the render the map tiles (Open street map). Everything is served by `ngnix` and if a open `http:localhost:90` the web app appears and everything works fine.

For semplicity, this is the snippet in map.html that communicate with `maptiles_server`:

```
       var tile_layer_66545a643ac9b27ac1858a48bb297727 = L.tileLayer(
            "http://localhost:3065/styles/basic-preview/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", /*<-- The important line*/ 
            {"attribution": "\u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"https://stadiamaps.com/\"\u003eStadia Maps\u003c/a\u003e, \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"https://openmaptiles.org/\"\u003eOpenMapTiles\u003c/a\u003e \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e contributors", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
        ).addTo(map_9e81a6b5e317b986bd330ec2a9330ff0);
```

Once I run `docker compose up` I can reach `http:localhost:90` from browser on my machine but when I try to access from another device (a smartphone on same network using `192.168.1.39:90`) the web app is reachable but the map doesn't render because is not able to reach `maptiles_server` because is trying to reach the `maptiles_server` on the device itself (the smartphone in this case).

I have tried to change `localhost` to `maptiles_server` in `map.html` file but this make map to not render also on my machine browser.

I have a docker compose with this 3 services:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

maptiles_server:
 image: maptiler/tileserver-gl:v4.1.2
 container_name: maptiles_server
 ports:
   - 3065:80
 volumes:
   - .\\app\\static\\assets\\maptiles:/data
 command: --mbtiles 2017-07-03_italy_milan.mbtiles

app:
 build: .
 ports:
  - 8000:2323
 container_name: flask_app
 links: 
   - maptiles_server

nginx:
 container_name: nginx
 build: .\ngnix
 # Bind the port 80 of container to machine port 80
 ports:
   - 90:80
 # Make app as nginx dependency service
 depends_on:
   - app
   - maptiles_server
```

The `app` expose a route to show a HTML map with some coordinates and use `maptiles_server` the render the map tiles (Open street map). Everything is served by `ngnix` and if a open `http:localhost:90` the web app appears and everything works fine.

For semplicity, this is the snippet in map.html that communicate with `maptiles_server`:

```
       var tile_layer_66545a643ac9b27ac1858a48bb297727 = L.tileLayer(
            "http://localhost:3065/styles/basic-preview/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", /*<-- The important line*/ 
            {"attribution": "\u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"https://stadiamaps.com/\"\u003eStadia Maps\u003c/a\u003e, \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"https://openmaptiles.org/\"\u003eOpenMapTiles\u003c/a\u003e \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e contributors", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
        ).addTo(map_9e81a6b5e317b986bd330ec2a9330ff0);
```

Once I run `docker compose up` I can reach `http:localhost:90` from browser on my machine but when I try to access from another device (a smartphone on same network using `192.168.1.39:90`) the web app is reachable but the map doesn't render because is not able to reach `maptiles_server` because is trying to reach the `maptiles_server` on the device itself (the smartphone in this case).

I have tried to change `localhost` to `maptiles_server` in `map.html` file but this make map to not render also on my machine browser.